# Installing Python with MySQL connector on Red Hat

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm having trouble making MySQL connector work with Python.

- I started with a fresh new installation of Red Hat 6.4.
- The system already had Python 2.6.6 installed by default, I need however version 3.4
- I downloaded, compiled and installed Python 3.4 from here (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tgz)
- I downloaded and installed the MySQL yum repository from here (http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm)
- Installed mysql-community-server version 5.7 with yum
- Finally I installed mysql-connector-python with yum (version 2.1.3)

Now it looks like the module works in Python 2.6.6 but it can't find the module with Python 3.4.

I'm a bit stuck with how to get round this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you got the mysql-connector via yum, it's installed for the system python. Your custom python 3 environment doesn't know about it.

So it's probably best to do the following:

1. Get [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and install it for your python 3. Make sure that `python` points to your custom installation when executing `python get_pip.py`
2. Get the source distribution of the `mysql-connector`: https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz
3. Use your just installed pip to install the `mysql-connector` from source into your python environment: `pip install path/to/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz`

Alternatively you might look into using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Comment: thanks, I got to point 3, where I'm trying to install the mysql connector with pip. Do I need to use pip3.4 which I assume is the one belonging to my python3.4?

Comment: Yep - sounds right. You can check it's part of your python3.4 using `which pip3.4`

Comment: Right, now in python3.4 if I do import mysql I don't get an error but help("modules") does not list mysql and msql.connector throws an error claiming module has no such attribute.

Comment: If I start python3.4 with sudo, it works... How can I make it accessible to all users?